# Encode object in Java decode in Android

Tags: java, android, base64, decode, encode

Is there any difference between Java and Android Base64 encode/decode ?
I'm trying to encode an object on my java server and decode on my android app, but getting something completely different.
(I know that it can be done with JSON).

On the JAVA Server :

```
public static String toString( Serializable o ) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
        oos.writeObject( o );
        oos.close();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray()); 
}
```

On Android app:

```
public static Object fromString( String s ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    byte [] data = Base64.decode( s, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(  data ) );
    Object o  = ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return o;
}
```

Some more data:

The test object is

```
new String("igor")

encoded in java : rO0ABXQABGlnb3I=
decoded in android : data = [-84 -19 0 5 116 0 4 105 103 111 114]
```

The function crushes on ois.readObject();

Is there any other way to send objects from server to client ?

Comment: Serialization algorithm should fail if the Base64 is different and broken binary data are coming to the ObjectInputStream. It will also check if it is the same base class. As a result, getting something "completely different" is unlikely; at least you need to explain more about this. If the binary data are different, could you include the fragment of the initial data, and data after transforming. If exception is thrown, which one? If the object is wrongly initialized, we need the source code fragment of the broken part of the object. Not enough details to understand what is going  wrong.

Comment: you can send the object from java to android without doing that .. also without using json

Comment: @ArolaAb How can I do that ?

Comment: please edit your question before i give you the answer

Answer (score 0):

To send an object from the java server to the android app :

1. Create your class and implements Serializable in the java project on the server.
2. Generate the serialversionuid to the class , this serialversionuid
   will guaranty that the same object is recived/sended , you can do
   that on eclpise by putting the mouse over the class name and press generate
   serial verison id.
3. Export your class as a jar and save it somewhere on your disk drive.
4. Delete the class from your project.
5. Import the jar witch you created in both android and java.
6. Use ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream and all the methods related
   to send the object.

To read the object that has been send :

```
Myclass m = (Myclass) ObjectInputStream.readObject();
```

Please Note this method Can be done using sockets , If you want to send it over http  you can send it as  a json format and use the Gson library to convert the json string to an object.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but I wanted to send it over http without json

Comment: What is the hint you have give it to the android app to know that the string you have encoded is an object and it should be converted to the same type of class ?